# Original / old English word for Metal or Metalcraft

Tags: old-english, germanic-languages

I would like to write my story in Anglish, which is basically, to my understanding, English without borrowed words from other languages. I like it because it sounds familiar and strange at the same time.

For example, carpenters would be woodworkers and carpentry would be woodcraft.

So far so good, but I struggle with metalworkers and metalcraft because as far as I can tell, metal is a relatively new addition to the English language and it is originally a Greek word.

I've done some Internet research, but the only useful thing I could find out was that "smith" is supposedly the original English word for a metalworker. That doesn't help me with the original word for metal, though. I'm pretty sure there is something I just don't understand...

So my question is, what would be an old / original English word for metal and metalcraft?

Comment: *Lead, gold, silver, copper, tin, brass, iron*, and *steel* are all Old English words. It's not clear to me that they had a word that encompassed all of these. The words for *metal* in the other West Germanic languages, Dutch and German, are *metaal* and *Metall.* There is a word in the North Germanic languages, Swedish and so forth, but its cognate in Middle English, *malme*, meant sand.

Comment: There was no Old English word for *metal* because (apparently) Old English speakers did not have a concept of metal as distinct from other materials.  "English" speakers did not group metals together until "French" people suggested it to them.  So, in your fantasy world, "foreign" concepts can be borrowed, but not the names of the concepts?

Comment: @Juhasz: I actually think it's possible that the Old English word for "metal" was "metal". We don't have a huge corpus of Old English writings, so if it was a rare word we might not know about it. And Old English [borrowed a bunch of words from Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_influence_in_English#Early_Middle_Ages) – maybe *metal* was one of them.

Comment: The Latin word **metallum** occuring in texts with Old English glosses is glossed with multiple Old English words, none of them ever a form of the word "metal", which is a good indication that *metal* had not become a loanword in Old English.

Answer (score 5):

One option from the Bosworth-Toller Dictionary online is *[smiþ-cræft](https://bosworthtoller.com/28163)* (smithcraft):

> Smithcraft, the craft or art of the worker in metal or wood

As people have pointed out, the material being worked is not specified in the name, though metal was often connected to smithing. (The verb *[be-smiþian](https://bosworthtoller.com/40147)* meant to work in metal.)

If you need to specify work in metal, a few other terms might work. For instance, a *geotere* ([Bosworth-Toller](https://bosworthtoller.com/15601)) was a founder, someone who poured metal into a mold or casted metal. The OED entry for "[yetter, n.](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/yetter_n?tab=meaning_and_use)" is more complete - *to yet* is to pour, so a *geotere*/*yetter* is literally a pourer of metal. Then *[slecg-wyrhta](https://bosworthtoller.com/58163)* is literally a *hammer-wright*, a metal worker, someone who would have hammered metal.

Finally, if you absolutely must have a metal material in the name, you could invent a term using an Old English word for metal. For instance, *[bloma](https://bosworthtoller.com/4735)* (modern *[bloom](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/bloom_n2?tab=etymology)*) was a mass of metal extracted from ore (compare: *[goldbloma](https://bosworthtoller.com/17352)* for mass of gold). *[Clympre](https://bosworthtoller.com/6398)* (modern *[clumper](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/clumper_n1?tab=meaning_and_use#9198370)*, but in Old English was clearly metal) and *[clyne](https://bosworthtoller.com/6400)* (no comparable modern term I know of) are two other example words, and I'm sure poking around Bosworth-Toller could give you further ideas. You could always create your own nonce usage: *bloomwright* or *clumpercraft*, or whatever works better for your fictional purposes.

Comment: +1  I think the Old English word **smylting** means "metal alloy". It appears in a gloss: **ferrum** *isen*  **electrum** *smylting*  (though I haven't seen the MS).

Comment: Great answer.  Old English _wír_ (_wir_)[*](https://bosworthtoller.com/35983) was used for metal also, but mainly for metal threads or ornamental metal. It could denote precious metals too. It is where the modern word _wire_ comes from.

Answer (score 2):

The word "metal" has been in the English language at least since the time of Chaucer, meaning that almost every English purist would probably include it in their "Anglish".

This [glossary of Chaucer](https://sites.fas.harvard.edu/%7Echaucer/glossar.htm) includes the word "metal" and gives the meaning as "metal". The Chaucerian verb meaning to craft metal is "forge".

Comment: I cannot upvote yet, thank you for the great resource!

Comment: Chaucer is Middle English, so After Conquest.  The question is what would it be in *Beowulf*. :)

Comment: @tchrist I only find results for a music band and a modern Aluminium company. I assume I don't know the proper methods and/or sources to find answers to that :/